# Splitting an integral into a sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

In one of the solutions to some of my exercise problems it says:

$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} f(x)\,dx \; + \; \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} f(1-x)\,dx$

Shouldn't it be:

$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} f(x)\,dx \; - \; \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} f(1-x)\,dx = F(1/2)\, - F(0) \, - F(1/2) \, + \, F(1) = F(1) - F(0) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx$

Answer (score 2):

It is
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1f(x)dx = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(x)dx + \int_\frac{1}{2}^1f(x)dx
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\int_\frac{1}{2}^1f(x)dx = -\int_\frac{1}{2}^0f(1-x)dx = \int_0^\frac{1}{2}f(1-x)dx
\end{align*}
thus your textbook is right. The mistake in your calculation is, that the antiderivative of $f(1-x)$ is not the same as the one of $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. But how is $
\int_\frac{1}{2}^1f(x)dx = -\int_\frac{1}{2}^0f(1-x)dx $

Comment: You substitute $(1-x)$ for $x$